# For each row of a DataFrame, get index of first column given condition into a new column

Tags: python, pandas

This is an extract of my Dataframe.

```
data = [
    ['1245', np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, ''],
    ['1246', np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ''],
    ['1247', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ''],
    ['1248', 1.0, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, ''],
    ['1249', np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, '']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['city_code', 'apr_12', 'may_12', 'jul_12', 'aug_12', 'first_index'])
```

[image: df]

I'd like to fill the "first_index" column with the index of the column (apr_12, may_12, jun_12 and aug_12) where there is the first "1.0" (float number).
For instance, I'd like to see in the column "first_index" of first row "2" as this is the position where stands the first "1.0" of the line. That would suppose, not taking into account the 'city_code' column also.

FYI: initially, NaN values were "0.0" (float number) but I thought it'd be easier to proceed with NaN values and functions such as `first_valid_index()` (but I can't make it work...). I'd have no issue putting back zeros if needed.

Do you guys have any idea on how to resolve this? Many thanks

Comment: please copy and paste an example of yuor dataframe. We will use `pd.read_clipboard` to read your dataframe and create a solution

Comment: @ansev Thanks. I've updated my question

Comment: @Grégoire de Kermel The dataframe example is good -- it is also helpful in general if you post an "expected" output example to clarify the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take each row and use np.where to find the first non null value index

```
col_list = ['apr_12', 'may_12', 'jul_12', 'aug_12']
df['first_index'] = df[col_list].apply(lambda x: (np.where(~x.isnull())[0][0]), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  city_code  apr_12  may_12  jul_12  aug_12  first_index
0      1245     NaN     NaN     1.0     1.0            2
1      1246     NaN     1.0     1.0     1.0            1
2      1247     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0            0
3      1248     1.0     1.0     NaN     NaN            0
4      1249     NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0            1
```

Using argmax or argmax as suggested by Stef will return the index of the max and min value (nanargmin/nanargmax ignores nan), so if your df values are not all 1's then it will fail to give the first non-nan index.

Answer (score 4):

Given you only have NaN and 1.0, you can do:

```
df['first_index'] = df[['apr_12', 'may_12', 'jul_12', 'aug_12']].fillna(0).to_numpy().argmax(1)
```

Result:

```
  city_code  apr_12  may_12  jul_12  aug_12  first_index
0      1245     NaN     NaN     1.0     1.0            2
1      1246     NaN     1.0     1.0     1.0            1
2      1247     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0            0
3      1248     1.0     1.0     NaN     NaN            0
4      1249     NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0            1
```

(if you have zeros instead of NaNs in the original version, as you said, then you can skip the `fillna(0)` of course)

Or shorter (for df with NaNs):

```
df['first_index'] = np.nanargmin(df[['apr_12', 'may_12', 'jul_12', 'aug_12']], 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `idxmax` and `get_indexer`:

```
data = [
    ['1245', np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, ''],
    ['1246', np.nan, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ''],
    ['1247', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ''],
    ['1248', 1.0, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan, ''],
    ['1249', np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 1.0, '']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['city_code', 'apr_12', 
                                   'may_12', 'jul_12', 'aug_12', 'first_index'])

df_out = df.set_index('city_code')
df_out['first_index'] = df_out.iloc[:,:-1].idxmax(axis=1)

df_out['position_first_index'] = df_out.columns.get_indexer(df_out['first_index'])

df_out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  city_code  apr_12  may_12  jul_12  aug_12 first_index  position_first_index
0      1245     NaN     NaN     1.0     1.0      jul_12                     2
1      1246     NaN     1.0     1.0     1.0      may_12                     1
2      1247     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0      apr_12                     0
3      1248     1.0     1.0     NaN     NaN      apr_12                     0
4      1249     NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0      may_12                     1
```